# How do I change the background of base template in the child template in django

Tags: html, django

So what i want is to change the css that was applied to some elements that are not part of any block in the Base.html to be able to change in the child templates. How do I do it?

Base.html:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body background='img.jpg'>{% block content %}Hello world{% endblock %}</body>
</html>
```

child.html:

```
{% extends 'Base.html' %}
<!-- Here i want to change the background that was applied to the body in Base.html -->
```

Comment: Maybe add a style block at the top of the documentation but after `{% extends 'Base.html' %}` that targets Body and use css to change the background.

Comment: @doniyor yes thats exactly what i want to do...but more importantly how to change the css of such elements.

Comment: @qasimalbaqali can you write a quick code of what you are tying to tell?

Comment: Look at the HTML block https://jsfiddle.net/twfx7s78/

Comment: @qasimalbaqali its not working :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body {% block bg %}background='img.jpg' class="base_bg_class"{% endblock %}>{% block content %}Hello world{% endblock %}    </body>
</html>
```

in child html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block bg %}
  background="child_background.jpg" class="child_bg_class"
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}....{% endblock %}
```

Comment: And what if I would have applied this background through css rather than through html tag??